# React/ TypeScript Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am struggling with the following error:

```
Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, getModifierState, and 8 more.  TS2345

    166 |                     autoComplete="off"
    167 |                     onChange={(event): void => {
  > 168 |                         setSearchInput(checkIfThereIsColon(event, event.target.value));
        |                                                            ^
    169 |                     }}
    170 |                     onKeyDown={(e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    171 |                         if (!isUserTyping) {
```

I have a component that is taking search input:

```
            onChange={(event): void => {
                setSearchInput(checkIfThereIsColon(event, event.target.value));
            }}
            onKeyDown={(e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                if (!isUserTyping) {
                    setIsUserTyping(true);
                }
                if (e.key === ':') {
                    disallowFilteringInSearchBar(e);
                }
            }}
```

Then it checks if the user typed a colon:

const disallowFilteringInSearchBar = (e: KeyboardEvent,  ) => {
e.preventDefault();
setIsUserTyping(false);
setModalAlert(true);
setFiltersModalOpen(true)
};

And also checks if a user pasted a colon from clipboard:

```
  function checkIfThereIsColon(event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>, eventTargetValue:string) {
    let searchStringStrippedOutColon = eventTargetValue;
    if (eventTargetValue.includes(":")) {
        searchStringStrippedOutColon = eventTargetValue.replace(/:/g, '<disallowed character>');
        disallowFilteringInSearchBar(event);
    }

    return searchStringStrippedOutColon;
  }
```

If I use `ts-ignore` to ignore the TS errors, all works fine.

I think I am not using the right type here:
`event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Anybody can suggest what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Is it really the  wrong type?

I have also tried to replace:

```
event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
```

with

```
event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
```

But it also doesn't fix it

Comment: Changing to `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>` should work. What's the error you get when you change the `checkIfThereIsColon` to above?

Comment: Inside the if function `disallowFilteringInSearchBar(event);` it underlines `event` and says: `Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.` `Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, getModifierState, and 8 more.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` event won't/cannot be a `KeyboardEvent` because of the fact that `onChange` can be triggered by non-keyboard events as compared. All the methods using the `event` param has to be `ChangeEvent`.

In your case, both declarations `checkIfThereIsColon(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>)` and `disallowFilteringInSearchBar(ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>)` I guess from what I see.

Comment: Thanks, but after changing those types I have the next error here: `if (e.key === ':') {disallowFilteringInSearchBar(e);}` it says `Argument of type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'.`

Comment: I'm not sure how your code flows, but all the dependant methods to accept `ChangeEvent` for this to work.